# Test if a div doesn't have an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to do something if a div contains a certain element, but can't seem to trigger the condition. Here's my best shot.

```
<div class='test'>
    testing123
</div>

<div class='test'>
  <p>testing456</p>
</div>

$('.test').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).has('p')) {
        $(this).addClass('red');
    }
});
```

the script is just targeting absolutely everything.
Here is a live fiddle - http://jsbin.com/igoyuk/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be aware that [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) **returns jQuery**, not a boolean !

> **.has( selector ) Returns: jQuery**
>   Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

Doing `if(!$(this).has('p'))` is always true, as jQuery always returns a set, even if it is empty !

`.has()` basically filters the set it is called upon, so you just have to do:

```
$('.test').has('p').addClass('red');
```

Comment: That's great, how can I do the reverse i.e. 'does not have' p ? thanks

Comment: Like this for instance: `$('.test:not(:has(p))')`

Comment: Brilliant, you got the vote because you explained why it didn't work :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!($(this).find('p').length > 0)) {
    $(this).addClass('red');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the following:

```
$("div.test:has(p)").addClass("red");
```

This queries your DOM for `<div>` elements, selecting only those with the *test* class and then looks to see if it has a `<p/>` element. Its a bit more terse = fewer bytes going over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following condition to check for the absence of an element type:

```
if($('p', $(this)).length == 0)
```

Since `$('p', $(this))` will return all of the `p` elements inside the current element.